# Can't run windows installer from usb on laptop

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, toshiba-laptop

I'm trying to install windows 10 on a Toshiba laptop (ref.: satellite cl15t-b1204). 
I used the [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool), but when I try start the laptop from the USB this message appear on the screen

```
Reboot and select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device an press a key
```

The strange thing is that Linux distro like Linux Mint or Ubuntu copied in the same USB run perfectly

For copy the Linux distro into the USB I used the command `dd` in bash.

EDIT:
This is the boot configuration available on the "TOSHIBA Setup Utility" further the "boot device priority"

BIOS setup screenshot:

[image]

Comment: "but when i try start the laptop from the usb this message appear on the screen" - Do you have CSM enabled or disabled?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure. I will edit the question with a snapshot of the "BIOS" setup of the laptop.

Comment: To make it easier on yourself Secure Boot should be enabled.  But your screenshot still doesn't answer my question

Comment: I mean, i don't know how to enable the CSM. That option doesn't appear in the _Toshiba setup utility_

Comment: You don't want to enable CSM.  Just, Enable Secure Boot, then install Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If secure boot was enabled UEFI will be too, secure boot only works in UEFI mode. OEM's love secure boot.

The USB drive is possibly MBR formatted as Microsoft USB tool instructions refer to XP. 
A UEFI BIOS won't boot from an MBR partition.

To boot from MBR disable secure boot and enable legacy BIOS support.

To complicate things further, if the laptop HDD is GPT (possible with 8.1 preinstalled) the OS install media be UEFI compatible.

GPT only boots from UEFI BIOS. Meaning legacy mode won't work for the installation.

Alternatively you could reformat the laptop as MBR.

The above only applies to boot drives, other drives can be formatted in whatever way you want.

For USB installs RUFUS works better than any Microsoft tools.....:)
http://www.techspot.com/downloads/6062-rufus.html

Comment: Thanks, i use RUFUS and use the option "_GPT for BIOS or UEFI_", it Works perfectly.

Comment: No problem. I know UEFI can be a pain...